# Sort by average rating between 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `ranks` which stores a 1-7 value and connects it with an item and user id. An item's rating is the average of all ratings it has been given.

Ranks table: `id | userid | value | itemid.`

To sort by average highest rating, I do (from an answer here):

```
select avg(value), itemid
from ranks
group by itemid
order by avg(value) desc
```

However, I also want to be able to filter items with a certain rating, not just highest rated -> lowest rated. For example, items with an average rating beteen 5 and 6.

```
select avg(value), itemid
from ranks
having avg(value) between 5 and 6
group by itemid
order by avg(value) desc
```

This gives me a nonspecific error at `group by`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `having` clause needs to come after your `group by` clause, so just reverse the order they appear in:

```
select avg(value), itemid
from ranks
group by itemid
having avg(value) between 5 and 6
order by avg(value) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(
select avg(value) as avgval, itemid
from ranks
group by itemid) t
where avgval between 5 and 6;
```

You can do it with a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

```
with Temp as 
(
select avg(value) [rating], itemid
from ranks
)
Select * from Temp
Where rating between 5 and 6
group by itemid
order by rating desc
```